# Dataweave change date

Tags: dataweave

I have a script like this:

```
%dw 2.0    
output application/csv  
---
payload.data map (item, index)  -> {
        created_time: item.created_time as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"},
}
```

And the created_time is "2021-11-29T13:02:04+0000" and I would like change the date to a different format, but the format doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: When you say created_time, do you mean the input or the output? You should provide the input, the expected output and the actual output so others can understand what are you trying to do and the issue you are having. Think on how others can reproduce the issue. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to further improve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input created_time is a String not really a Date or a DateTime. That means that the type coercion (`as String`) doesn't use the format. You need first to convert the input from String to a DateTime and then to a String with your desired format. Remember that the format is used for conversions only. Dates don't have a specific format in DataWeave nor in Java.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
payload.data map ( item, index) -> {
    created_time: item.created_time as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxx"} as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}
}
```